# How can I add new information to a .txt file without it removing any old data in java

Tags: java, txt

I want to store all the sales in a txt file, but every time I enter new information it deletes the old information. Any idea why?

```
try {
    BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1));
    BufferedWriter bfw1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file2));

    bfw.write(Total.getText());
    bfw.newLine();

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
    bfw1.write(timeStamp);
    bfw1.newLine();

    bfw.close();
    bfw1.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FrmFacturas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a second parameter to the FileWriter constructor:

`BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1, true));`

OR

you could use Files.nio:

`Files.writeString(file1.toPath(), textToWrite, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)`

Comment: I Tried this 

File t = new File(file1);
   Files.writeString(t.toPath(), Total.getText(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

but didnt work im getting an error in writeString

Comment: which error did you get?

Comment: It worked, with the fileriter, Than you!

Comment: can u pls set this as accepted answer then? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the file in append mode to do this add true as the second parameter in FileWriter

```
BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1,true));
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but It didnt work

Comment: seems like you wish to append the timestamp try using this code

String textToAppend = "yourtimestamp";
     
        //Set true for append mode
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new FileWriter("c:/temp/samplefile.txt", true));    
 
    writer.write(textToAppend);
    writer.close();